# How did testnet transaction b6714e05dd014cc92de09271886e62d85e7d41dd44fad417c520eb51d57f94c0 validate?

Tags: transactions, script

Testnet transaction `c474c67cabc13f74c65e7cf503db971d5ba176794bff7de36f46d51ca675cf3a` locked 0.0005BTC with a simple math script:

```
OP_2DUP
OP_ADD
5102
OP_EQUALVERIFY
OP_SUB
230d
OP_EQUAL
```

Transaction `b6714e05dd014cc92de09271886e62d85e7d41dd44fad417c520eb51d57f94c0` spent that output with the sigscript:

```
ba07
6985
```

I can't see how `(ba07 + 6985) == 5102` or `(ba07 - 6985) == 230d`.

What am I missing about Bitcoin script, integers, and math?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For mathematical operations, Bitcoin treats byte vectors as signed (signed magnitude) little endian values. So let's look what the numbers are then:

- The byte vector `ba07` is the hexadecimal number (0)7ba.
- The byte vector `6985` is `8569` in big endian. Since the highest bit is set the number is negative. So the hexadecimal number is -(0)569.
- The byte vector `5102` is the hexadecimal number (0)251.
- The byte vector `0d23` is the hexadecimal number (0)23d.

Therefore we end up with the two statements `7ba+(-569)=251` and `7ba-(-569)=d23` which are true.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks!  I had tried playing with the sign bits, but I didn't realize it was little-endian on top of all that.